# Break sentence line with hyphen if word is too long in android jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to break line with hyphen if word is too long to fit in.

for example:

```
|<----screen space----->|

"This is example of veryLongWord." // very long sentence :P

Currently sentence line break like this.

|<------screen space------>|
This is example of |<----->|empty space
veryLongWord.



I want to achieve this:

|<------screen space------>|
This is example of veryLon-
gWord.
```

Comment: Seems not to be possible right know. But there is a Issue open at Google's issuetracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122476122
Please vote to increase the chances to get this anytime soon!
For now, it is a possible workaround to embed a classical `TextView` within your Jetpack Compose Application using `AndroidView` Composable.

Answer (score 1):

if replace space to "\u00A0", it will work.
cause your text to be treated as a single string.

Text(
...
text = "your text".replace(" ", "\u00A0"),
...
)

Comment: This breaks the long word into multiple lines. But still, the word is not hyphenated between the lines.  Image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cKnL.png

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31978049)

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood the problem

Answer (score 0):

So before anyone come to the rescue, as far as I looked into the Text() API, there is no solution for what you want out of the box.

Even then it does not sound like what you are looking for, the only ready to use solution I know is.

```
        Text(
        ...
            textAlign = TextAlign.Justify,
            softWrap = true
        ...
        )
```

Comment: TextAlign.Justify might help

Comment: Nope.. this is not what i want.. thanks for your time.

Comment: No problem, I hope I at least showed you how not to do :D

Comment: There is something called paragraph it has attribute called line break but i'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: this dude has a very good article on the Text component; https://joebirch.co/android/exploring-jetpack-compose-text/

Comment: This is what I had in mind but I can't find how to use it in compose: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/text/LineBreaker